# Restoring VMware VCenter backup from 6.0 to 6.0 fails

Tags: postgresql, backup

I'm trying to restore the backup taken on VCenter 6.0, but it fails with errors as below:

Snippet of Console Log:

```
NOTICE:  constraint "cl_fk_entity_lock_metadata" of relation "cl_entity_lock_metadata" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  drop cascades to constraint fk_library_id on table cl_library_storage
NOTICE:  drop cascades to constraint fk_storage_id on table cl_library_storage
NOTICE:  constraint "fk_storage_id" of relation "cl_library_storage" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  constraint "fk_library_id" of relation "cl_library_storage" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  drop cascades to constraint vdc_entity_lock_metadata_fk on table vdc_entity_lock_metadata
NOTICE:  constraint "vdc_entity_lock_metadata_fk" of relation "vdc_entity_lock_metadata" does not exist, skipping
```

Snippet of Restore Log:

```
psql:C:/ProgramData/VMware/vCenterServer/logs/create_constr2018052604370105.sql:101: ERROR:  could not create unique index "pk_vpx_host_node_cpu"
DETAIL:  Key (host_id, numa_id, cpu_id)=(29, 1, 23) is duplicated.
psql:C:/ProgramData/VMware/vCenterServer/logs/create_constr2018052604370105.sql:775: ERROR:  could not create unique index "pk_vpx_dbm_counter_metadata"
DETAIL:  Key (counter_id)=(1) is duplicated.
psql:C:/ProgramData/VMware/vCenterServer/logs/create_constr2018052604370105.sql:808: ERROR:  insert or update on table "vpx_virtual_ethernet_card" violates foreign key constraint "fk_vpx_virtual_ethernet_card"
DETAIL:  Key (vdevice_id)=(516) is not present in table "vpx_virtual_device".
psql:C:/ProgramData/VMware/vCenterServer/logs/create_constr2018052604370105.sql:824: ERROR:  insert or update on table "vpx_datastore" violates foreign key constraint "fk_vpx_ds_ref_vpx_entity"
```

DB i'm using is Postgres, Backup was taken from VCenter 6.0 binary 3d and I tried restoring the backup on  different binaries 3, 3d, 3e in all the cases the OS and VCenter was freshly installed with clean DB.

This might not be the complete information, but please let me know if you need any additional logs or any inputs from my side.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Looks like your original database is corrupted. But perhaps the problem is the way you took the backup.

Comment: I have scheduled the backups to be stored in backup server and even tried one of the oldest backup still I got the same error.

Comment: You probably suffered data corruption long ago. You'll have to remove duplicates before you can restore the constraints.